# Finding one time occurrences of a character

Tags: regex

I am struggling to solve a particular regex problem. I want to find occurences of a character `X` in a text, that are not next to another occurrence of `X`.

```
"Hello X!"         //- 1 find
       ^
"Hello XX!"        //- No find

"X! Hello! X!"     //- 2 finds
 ^         ^
"Hello XXX!"       //- No find
```

Comment: You could use negative lookarounds (so long as you aren't using Javascript): `(?<!X)X(?!X)` or, if you are using Javascript, `[^X]X[^X]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use negative lookarounds (so long as you aren't using Javascript): `(?<!X)X(?!X)` or, if you are using Javascript, `(?:[^X]|^)X(?:[^X]|$)`

[PCRE Example](http://regex101.com/r/xO9cT8/1)

[JavaScript Example](http://regex101.com/r/xO9cT8/3)

Comment: Thank you! I finally understood the negative lookbehind/lookahead thing

Comment: It was confusing to me at first as well, it just takes time sometimes.

Comment: Note that `[^X]X[^X]` requires that there is *some* character before and after the `X`, i.e., it will not match if your `X` is the first or last character in your string.